# mysql multiple updates only if one field is null

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update

let's say that I have a a field named "control".
If "control" is null, than I have to update fields "control", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5".
If "control" is NOT null, I have only to update "f4" and "f5".
How am I supposed to achieve this goal?
I tried something like:

```
UPDATE table SET 
control = IF(control IS NULL, 1, do_nothing), 
f1 = IF(control IS NULL, value1, do_nothing),
f2 = IF(control IS NULL, value2, do_nothing),
f3 = IF(control IS NULL, value3, do_nothing),
f4 = value4,
f5 = value5
WHERE id = XX
```

but "control" once being set to 1 is not null anymore, so other updates (but the f4 and f5) are not processed.
Moreover, how do I tell in the if statement to "do_nothing" on the ELSE branch?
Getting confused.
I thought to make a select and a nested update, but got many errors.
Thanks everyone

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use an update statement for f4 and f5, and then a separate statement for the other columns. You might be able to get a single update statement that does all that, but why work that hard?

Comment: Excercise :) Seriously, because I wanna stay "light" with the script page, I want to learn something complex about UPDATE statement that I am missing and because I think it could be elegant having everything in a single query. I think that I have all the instruments to achieve that, but I'm not able to mix them up in the right "recipe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Thanks for the advice.
To whom may be useful:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE `setLastLogin` 
(
  IN  `ip_user`  varchar(255),
  IN  `user_id`  int
)
BEGIN
  /* Procedure text */

  SELECT control INTO @con
  FROM tbl_users
  WHERE id = user_id;

  IF (@con IS NULL) 
  THEN
     UPDATE tbl_users
     SET
     control = 1,
     date_control = NOW(),
     ip_control = ip_user,
     date_last_login = NOW(),
     ip_last_login = ip_user
     WHERE id = user_id;
  ELSE
     UPDATE tbl_users
     SET
     date_last_login = NOW(),
     ip_last_login = ip_user
     WHERE id = user_id;

  END IF;


END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure or this can be achieved with two statements.

```
UPDATE table SET 
control = 1,
f1 = value1, 
f2 = value2, 
f3 = value3, 
f4 = value4,
f5 = value5
WHERE id = XX and control IS NULL
```

and

```
UPDATE table SET
f4 = value4,
f5 = value5
WHERE id = XX and control IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
update table
set f1 = case when control is null
              then 'value1' else f1
         end,
    f2 = case when control is null
              then 'value2' else f2
         end,
    f3 = case when control is null
              then 'value3' else f3
         end,
    f4 = 'value4',
    f5 = 'value5'
where id = XX;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the IF condition:

```
IF control IS NULL AND ID=XX THEN UPDATE table SET 
    control = 1,
    f1 = value1, 
    f2 = value2, 
    f3 = value3, 
    f4 = value4,
    f5 = value5

ELSEIF control IS NOT NULL THEN UPDATE table SET
    f4 = value4,
    f5 = value5

END IF
```

Comment: nice one. Thanks. I ended up with a stored procedure, but your code is what I was initially looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is not a super upgrade against what has already been shown, but in case somebody finds it useful, you can do this

```
UPDATE table SET 
control = IF(control IS NULL, 1, control ), 
f1 = IF(control IS NULL, value1, f1),
f2 = IF(control IS NULL, value2, f2),
f3 = IF(control IS NULL, value3, f3),
f4 = value4,
f5 = value5
WHERE id = XX
```

And thus, keeping the old value